# No such file or directory error on VSCode while running a python script with poetry and pyenv

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pyenv, python-poetry

I'm having a problem when accessing a file path while using python in VSCode with pyenv and poetry on Ubuntu 20.04.

I run this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("../docs/lists.csv")
data
```

And I got this error:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../docs/lists.csv'
  File "/home/nisase/my_folder/examples/list.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv("../docs/lists.csv")`
```

Project tree is below:

```
my_folder/
 |examples/             
    |list.py
 |docs/              
    |lists.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `data = pd.read_csv("docs/lists.csv")`?

The python script to search the file depends on the `cwd`, you can get it through `os.getcwd`.

> os.getcwd()
>
> Return a string representing the current working directory.

The default value of `cwd` in VSCode is:

```
${workspaceFolder} - the path of the folder opened in VS Code
```

So the path is `docs/lists.csv` instead of `../docs/lists.csv`